# Why do I get "undeclared identifier" when I declared the identifier in a shader.replace function?

Tags: three.js, shader

The context of my query is one where I have just loaded a GLTF model and am making some shader modifications to the material using **shader.onBeforeCompile**.  I had successfully performed this same process before and am stumped as to why I am getting an "undeclared identifier" error.

The error:
[image: error]

The relevant code:

```
material.onBeforeCompile = shader => {

shader.vertexShader = shader.vertexShader.replace(
    '#define STANDARD',
    `#define STANDARD
    out float styleValue;`
).replace(
    '#include <common>',
    `#include <common>
    in float style;`
).replace(
    '#include <project_vertex>',
    `#include <project_vertex>
     styleValue=style;`
);


shader.fragmentShader = shader.fragmentShader.replace(
        '#define STANDARD',
        `#define STANDARD
    in float styleValue;`
    )
    .replace(
        '#include <fog_fragment>',
        `#include <fog_fragment>
    int style = int(styleValue); 
    vec4 col;
    if (style == 0) {
      col = texture2D(map, vUv );
    } else if ( style==1) {
      col = texture2D(map, vUv + vec2(.5,0.) );
    } 
       gl_FragColor = col;` );

};
```

Comment: What type of material do you try to modify?

Comment: It is a PBR material.  That ended up being the issue as #define STANDARD wasn't present in the shaders to replace.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

While logging the vertex and fragment shaders during the onBeforeCompile I noticed that #define STANDARD was not present.  I modified the related string replace and it now works.